# problem with integers

Tags: java

can anybody look at this code and tell me why the exception happens?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int total =100;
    int discount_Ammount = 20 ;
       int newAccount=Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf(Math.floor(total - discount_Ammount)).trim());
}
```

Method floor returns double value , then I make casting to integer, so I cast it to string then to integer... please, can anybody help?

Comment: What Exception do you get? I'll guess a `ClassCastException`, but I shouldn't have to guess, and I could be wrong.

Comment: Why are you calling floor?  Subtracting two ints will give you an int.  No need to floor the subtraction.

Comment: My guess is that you are NOT reading the exception or don't understand what it says.  parseInt will only parse integers and you are giving it a decimal (as a String as input) i.e. you cannot parse 80.0 as an integer.  I suggest you think about the simplest way to do something not the most compilcated and it there will be less to go wrong. ;)

Answer (score 14):

You aren't "casting" anything. `trim()` removes whitespace only, which will never be present in the result of `String.valueOf(double)`.

Use a cast:

```
int newAccount = (int) Math.floor(total - discount_Ammount);
```

Java is a strongly typed programming language, not a scripting language. Implicit conversions between strings and other types are not supported.

Or, get rid of the `floor()` operation altogether, since you are working with an `int` quantity already, and `floor()` is meaningless:

```
int newAccount = total - discount_Ammount;
```

If you are working with money, use the `BigDecimal` class so that you can use the round-off rules required by your accounting system. You won't have control of that when using `double`.

Comment: in this code i use integer numbers , but in my program i am using double values so i need the floor operatoion, but (int ) make the casting very simple , thanx for BigDecimal  info and for the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try this?

```
int newAccount = (int) Math.floor(total - discount_Ammount);
```

Or even this!

```
int newAccount = total - discount_Ammount;
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to do Integer.parseInt( String.valueOf(

To cast to int, just do (int)(blah)

```
So int newAccount=(int)(Math.floor(total - discount_Ammount));
```